# Why does Jenkins have a ".mozilla" folder?

Tags: firefox, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I have two instances of Jenkins and am trying to replicate the functionality of one in the other.

The original instance has a ".mozilla" folder at "/var/lib/Jenkins/.mozilla". The other does not. I was using that folder in the original instance (to set up firefox profiles for selenium to use to set up certificates).

What might explain this discrepancy? I do not remember doing anything deliberately to add the ".mozilla" folder, but it turns out I needed it.

*Old instance.*
[image: Original instance. With '.mozilla' folder.]

*New instance.*
[image: New instance. Without '.mozilla' folder.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Firefox driver creates a new profile every time a test launches the browser. According to mozilla, the folder where these profiles are saved is under `.mozilla` folder. See more information [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox)

> Linux Profile folders are located here:
>
> ~/.mozilla/firefox/ The ".mozilla" folder is a hidden
> folder. See this article for more information. To show hidden files in
> Nautilus (Gnome desktop's default file browser), choose "View -> Show
> Hidden Files".
>
> Mac Profile folders are in one of these locations:
>
> ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/
>
> ~/Library/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/

Comment: And it looks like that is . . . true . . . Once I got Jenkins to run firefox, the folder got created. I did not see it earlier, because my first attempts involved using profiles to employ certificates. It did not work, because I needed to add the profiles (and certificates, by extension) to the ".mozilla" folder. Once I used a non-certificate option, it looks like the folder got created. I now understand Mr. Richter's answer better after reading this. So, thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

The system user owning the Jenkins process has a `$HOME` directory (`/var/lib/Jenkins/` in your case) and starts all process started in Jenkins as this user. For those processes the `$HOME` directory is the same one and if any test, e.g. a functional Selenium test ever started a Firefox test, the directory remains there.